# Storing a dictionary/tuple in an Sqlite database for Python

Tags: python, database, dictionary, sqlite

I have a dictionary, where the key is a string and the value is a tuple of strings.
For example,

```
d = {"10A": ("A", "B", "c"), "10B": ("D", "A"), "13A": ("R", "Q", "T", "W", "P")}
```

The number of elements in the tuple is variable. What is the best and most efficient way to store this in an sqlite database?

Is there any way to store a tuple directly in a database? If i did that, then my table would contain only two columns - key and tuple.

Or should each string in the tuple have a separate column for itself?

Answer (score 1):

You could design a table like this:

```
id  key  value
0   10A  A
1   10A  B
2   10A  c
3   10B  D
4   10B  A
5   13A  R
...
```

The best solution would probably be to not use a relational database at all. If possible look in to MongoDB and other technology that's more suitable for key, value storage.